# why is this iife returning undefined, instead of 10?

Tags: javascript

Why is this immediately invoked function returning undefined instead of 10?

```
function test(){

    function test2(){
         return 10;
    }
    test2();
}
```

Comment: Where is the IIFE? Are you taking about `test2` (it's not a function expression)? It definitely returns 10.

Answer (score 1):

You need a return and a value for returning something different then the default return value of `undefined` in your [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Description).

> By default, functions return `undefined`. To return any other value, the function must have a return statement that specifies the value to return.

```js
function test(){

    function test2(){
         return 10;
    }
    return test2();
//  ^^^^^^
}

console.log(test());
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are not returning anything in `test()`

```js
function test(){

    function test2(){
         return 10;
    }

    return test2();
}

alert(test());
```